# Cannot add an ORDER BY command to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I'm converting a stored procedure in some software I'm maintaining from SQL Server SQL to Informix SQL, and problems are abundant.

Basically I'm converting each section line-by-line until I have the whole thing converted.

I have the following `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ifxdbase:dc_buildSP (WorkID INT, CompNo smallint)
CREATE TEMP TABLE Items
(
   Code smallint,
   Qty int,
   Total int
);

INSERT INTO Items
SELECT 
   tblDetails.code, 
   tblDetails.quantity,
   tblHead.quantity
FROM
   tblHead
INNER JOIN tblDetails ON (tblDetails.compno = tblDetails.compno AND tblDetails.id_num = tblHead.id_num)
WHERE tblHead.compno = CompNo AND tblHead.id_num = WorkID;
--ORDER BY tblDetails.code;

DROP TABLE Items;
END PROCEDURE
```

As it stands, this works fine, but when I uncomment the line `--ORDER BY tblDetails.seqno;` (and remove the semicolon from the previous line) I get a "-201 A syntax error has occurred" error.

Basically `tblHead` is a series of order headers and `tblDetails` is a table of the details of each of those orders. Selecting and joining the data works fine, trying to order it fails.

Ordering should work with anything from the original SELECT, IIRC, so I can't see what could be going wrong, here...

Comment: Why do you need an order by when inserting data into a table?

Comment: the problem is not the stored procedure, the problem is that an ORDER BY clausule is not allowed in a INSERT INTO ....SELECT construction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0878.htm#ids_sqs_0878):

> ..... not all clauses and options of
>   the SELECT statement are available for
>   you  to use in a query within an
>   INSERT statement. The following SELECT
>   clauses and  options are not supported
>   by Informix in an INSERT statement:
>
> FIRST and INTO TEMP
>
> ORDER BY and UNION

so ORDER BY is not supported in the INSERT command in Informix.

I don't have something to test right now, but you could try something like this, as a workaround:

```
INSERT INTO Items
SELECT code, dQuantity, hQuantity
  FROM (
    SELECT 
     tblDetails.code, 
     tblDetails.quantity dQuantity,
     tblHead.quantity hQuantity
    FROM
     tblHead
    INNER JOIN tblDetails ON (tblDetails.compno = tblDetails.compno AND tblDetails.id_num = tblHead.id_num)
    WHERE tblHead.compno = CompNo AND tblHead.id_num = WorkID;
    ORDER BY tblDetails.code
  );
```

Comment: Okay, fair enough. It works in SQL Server. As was mentioned by Lieven above, there's no real good reason for there to be an ORDER BY anyway. Thank you for your documentation reference and workaround suggestion.